# Implementing a text editor in Python

Tags: python, string

I need to create a program that asks the user to input a string and then pick one of the following txt editors to apply to it:

```
(lcase) make each letter lowercase
(ucase) make each letter uppercase
(alt) make each letter alternate in case, with first letter capitalized
(remspace) remove all white space
(1337) convert to l337-speak
(rev) reverse the string
(new) enter a new string
(restore) replace string with last one entered
(quit) exit the program
```

The program needs to run on a loop until the user enters quit.

This is my code so far but it doesn't really work (the prompts work perfectly, but I can't get the modifiers to work at all):

```
print "Welcome to the text converter. Your options are to:"
print "(lcase) make each letter lowercase"
print "(ucase) make each letter uppercase"
print "(alt) make each letter alternate in case, with first letter capitalized"
print "(remspace) remove all white space"
print "(1337) convert to l337-speak"
print "(rev) reverse the string"
print "(new) enter a new string"
print "(restore) replace string with last one entered"
print "(quit) exit the program"
print "-----------------------------------------------"
y = raw_input("Please enter a string: ")

def reverse_string(y):
    return y[:: -1]

x = raw_input("Action (lcase, ucase, alt, remspace, rev, new, restore, quit):")


while x == raw_input:
    if x == "lcase": 
        return str.lower(y)

    if x == "ucase":
        return y.upper(y)

    if x == "alt":
        return 

    if x == "remspace":
        return str.string(y)

    if x == "rev":
        return 

    if x == "restore":
        return y

    if x == "quit":
        print "See you next time!"
        exit()

    if x == "new":
        break 
        return raw_input()
```

Please help me fix my code.

Answer (score 2):

`while x == raw_input` will never be reached.
`return` should be inside of a function.

```
print "Welcome to the text converter. Your options are to:"
print "(lcase) make each letter lowercase"
print "(ucase) make each letter uppercase"
print "(alt) make each letter alternate in case, with first letter capitalized"
print "(remspace) remove all white space"
print "(1337) convert to l337-speak"
print "(rev) reverse the string"
print "(new) enter a new string"
print "(restore) replace string with last one entered"
print "(quit) exit the program"
print "-----------------------------------------------"

def reverse_string(y):
    return y[:: -1]

while True:
    y = raw_input("Please enter a string: ")
    x = raw_input("Action (lcase, ucase, alt, remspace, rev, new, restore, quit):")

    if x == "lcase": 
        print y.lower()

    if x == "ucase":
        print y.upper()

    if x == "alt":
        #Capitalize the first letter of each word in a string
        print y.title()

    if x == "remspace":
        # Replace each 'space' with ''
        print y.replace(' ', '')

    if x == "rev":
        #call 'reverse_string' to reverse 'y'
        print reverse_string(y)

    if x == "restore":
        print y

    if x == "quit":
        print "See you next time!"
        #breaks while loop
        break

    if x == "new":
        #Go to the next iteration (Ask user again)
        continue
```